# HTML Form action goto page

Tags: html, forms, authentication

For a Project, in which we are not yet allowed to use php, I want to create a login page. I just can't figure out how to make it so the cancel button and the submit button take me to predefined pages. I want to be able to input some dummy data into the username password fields and when I press submit be sent to the "logged in" part of my site.

```
<button type="submit" value="profil.html">Login</button>
```

I tried it like that but it doesn't work. I also tried that:

```
<form action="profil.html" method="get">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use little bit of js to achieve it cleanly.

`<button value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='otherpage.html'"> Cancel</button>`

Comment: And what should I write in the action?

Comment: Since its a simple button, form action doesn't have any effect here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the action in the form. Use a submit button to submit the data to that URL.

"Cancel" means "Give up on the form and go somewhere else". To go somewhere else: Use a link.

```
<button>Login</button>
<a href="/elsewhere">Cancel</a>
```